# Can a Git WebHook on Pull Request Comment publish the list of files changed

Tags: github-webhook

I have a Git WebHook message that is expected to react to a particular comment in a pull request. I had the following questions:

- Can the WebHook be triggered only for a certain text in the comment?
  e.g. 'Prepare for deployment'?
- Can the WebHook payload include the list of files changed? Right now there is a URL for the pull request,which can be invoked to get the list of files changed. Wanted to see if this call can be eliminated.

Thanks,
Prabal